# no module named ... try to importcustom python module from a notebook in google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

In a google drive, suppose a jupyter notebook and a python file my_module.py copied in the same directory. How to import my_module from the notebook when run with google colaboratory?

When the notebook is run locally, `import my_module` just works.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the welcome notebook at colab.research.google.com there's a link to an example notebook titled "Loading and saving data: local files, Drive, Sheets, Google Cloud Storage" (https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb).  This gives recipes for how to copy files from Google Drive to the colaboratory runtime which you can use to copy your module code so it will be visible to the runtime's import machinery.

Comment: I ran *Drive Fuse example.ipynb* The cell with:

Comment: I ran *Drive Fuse example.ipynb*  . **!ls drive/** returns everything from my googledrive, but I don't understand how to access to that that drive from python. For example, **os.getcwd()** just returns **/content**

Comment: Does this work for you?
`import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'drive'))`

Answer (score 0):

I has same problem before i fixed it. there is few way.

1.Use right python version, google colaboratory have 2 python version 2.7 and 3.6.1.

2.Add **init**.py blank content in directory, example:

```
dir/
__init__.py
my_module.py
yournotebook.ipynb
```

3.Remove all pycache *.pyc in dir/

```
cd dir
!rm *pyc
```

Comment: i tried this nothing happened. :( i am trying to run the  stanford cs231n assingmnet 1 using colab. but i am getting this error . ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cs231n'

Comment: @MituVinci I wonder if you're using python3, trying it by change to python 2.7 version. cs231 assignment code is wrote in python 2.7